# Unexpected NULL in multi-column correlated update

Tags: oracle, select, oracle11g, sql-update, subquery

I want to run a [multi-column correlated update](http://psoug.org/reference/update.html) of this kind:

```
UPDATE t1 t1_alias
SET (table_name, tablespace_name) = (
    SELECT table_name, tablespace_name
    FROM t2 t2_alias
    WHERE t1_alias.table_name = t2_alias.table_name
);
```

But my attempt:

```
update customer up
set (customer_name, account, active) = (
    select tmp.name, tmp.account, case when tmp.active = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end
    from customer_temp tmp
    where up.agent = substr(tmp.agent, -4) and up.customer_code = tmp.code
);
```

... throws:

> ```
> ORA-01407: cannot update ("FOO"."CUSTOMER"."CUSTOMER_NAME") to NULL
> ```

The source table `customer_temp` has no null values so I must be getting matches wrong. What is my error or misconception?

Comment: Seems `foo.customer.customer_name` is a not null column. And your `select` statement matched no results or its `tmp.name is null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, there are some rows in the target table that have no match in the subquery.

You can avoid this with by adding an `exists` condition that filters out "unmatched" rows:

```
update customer up
set (customer_name, account, active) = (
    select tmp.name, tmp.account, case when tmp.active = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end
    from customer_temp tmp
    where up.agent = substr(tmp.agent, -4) and up.customer_code = tmp.code
)
where exists (
    select 1
    from customer_temp tmp
    where up.agent = substr(tmp.agent, -4) and up.customer_code = tmp.code
);
```

Comment: Ah... My misunderstanding was assuming that the correlated subquery would affect the matching rows in the outer query. But it just determines the values to set, the row filter for DELETE is still outer WHERE's responsibility.